# Class compliant audio interface not detected anymore

Tags: sound, pipewire, pavucontrol

My Dell XPS 13 laptop runs Ubuntu 22.10 with Pipewire. I use an external audio interface, an RME Babyface Pro class compliant, both as an alternative general output and as a pro soundcard in Bitwig or other digital audio workstations. For the latter use, I configure the sound card as "Pro Audio" in pavucontrol, allowing me to benefit from its multiple inputs and outputs.

This interface has always worked very well, albeit with the occasional regulatory configuration hiccup, and the arrival of Pipewire has simplified things quite a bit in this respect.

Suddenly, as of today, the interface is no longer available in the audio output choices, either in the system settings or in the Bitwig preferences. However, it is recognized as a USB device:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 2a39:3fb0 RME Babyface Pro (Class Compliant Mode)
```

Any tips on how to debug and resolve the situation would be much appreciated.